# Reshape arrays with python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have the array

```
A = array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,  10.,  11.,  12.],
           [  4.,   5.,   6.,  13.,  14.,  15.],
           [  7.,   8.,   9.,  16.,  17.,  18.],
           [ 19.,  20.,  21.,  28.,  29.,  30.],
           [ 22.,  23.,  24.,  31.,  32.,  33.],
           [ 25.,  26.,  27.,  34.,  35.,  36.]])
```

I would like to reshape it in order to obtain

```
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]
```

I have tried

```
>>> B = A.reshape(1,36)
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,  10.,  11.,  12.,   4.,   5.,   6.,  13.,  14.,
         15.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  28.,
         29.,  30.,  22.,  23.,  24.,  31.,  32.,  33.,  25.,  26.,  27.,
         34.,  35.,  36.]])
```

But, obviously, I didn't reach the result. My real data differs from the example, so I can't sort the array `A` to obtain `B`.

I suppose I need more reshapes...

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Strictly speaking, `numpy.sort(A.flatten())` will achieve this result. But I'm guessing this isn't your real data and we can't rely on sorting to get the order that you want.

Comment: @PaulH I've edit the question. Your answer works for the example, but I can't use sort (I have random numbers)

Comment: I figured. Still need a few more details. How general of a solution are you trying to make? For example: are you always going to be dealing with a square array (N x N, where N is even) that is divided into quadrants? Or is it always divided up into any number of 3x3 chunks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split each of those two axes such that the remaining ones are of lengths `2` each with a `reshape` giving us a `4D` array and then swap the middle two axes with `np.swapaxes()` and finally flatten with `np.ravel()` -

```
A.reshape(2,3,2,3).swapaxes(1,2).ravel()
```

Generically put -

```
m,n = A.shape
A.reshape(2,m//2,2,n//2).swapaxes(1,2).ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: A
Out[15]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,  10.,  11.,  12.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,  13.,  14.,  15.],
       [  7.,   8.,   9.,  16.,  17.,  18.],
       [ 19.,  20.,  21.,  28.,  29.,  30.],
       [ 22.,  23.,  24.,  31.,  32.,  33.],
       [ 25.,  26.,  27.,  34.,  35.,  36.]])

In [16]: A.reshape(2,3,2,3).swapaxes(1,2).ravel()
Out[16]: 
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,
        12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,
        23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.,  30.,  31.,  32.,  33.,
        34.,  35.,  36.])
```